# Is there any difference between the colours of PokeBeans?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

In Pokemon Refresh and Poke Pelago, you receive and use Pokebeans.  These come in a wide variety of colours - with no stated difference between them (except for the clearly-special Rainbow and Crystal beans).

For the standard coloured beans, is there any difference between them?  For example, do certain Pokemon like a particular colour's flavour better in Refresh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/pokebeans.shtml) (perhaps one of the most reliable sources on Pokemon information) the color differences are purely aesthetic.